# Hot to get last 30 records of collection result in mongodb, but not from zero?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to make this with `.sort({_id:1}).limit(30)` but in result they are showing from 0 to 30, but not from 40 to 70 (for example), that's mean i see all messages to 30, and newer than 30 - not showing. How i can find out actually 30 messages from db.collection('messages') ?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the first document to be included in the results by calling [`skip()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#skip) on the cursor:

```
.sort({_id: 1}).skip(40).limit(30)
```

Would provide the 41 through 70 documents after sorting by `_id`.

If you want to get the *last* 30 while keeping them in ascending order, reverse your sort, and then reverse the results using [`Array#reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```
coll.find().sort({_id: -1}).limit(30).toArray((err, docs) => {
    docs.reverse();    
});
```

Comment: but 40 and 70 - it was example. I need to get from last N (may be 70 or 100, whatever) results 30 cols from end, not in reverse order. Reverse order work fine for me, but its showing messages from newest to older, not what i exactly needed

Comment: @DanialartBiz Then reverse the sort  with `sort({_id: -1})` and then reverse the returned docs in your own code, possibly using [`Array#reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

Comment: Thank you, its work, but not be easy to get count of entries in collection, then minus 30, so we get number of cursor we need to skip to get last 30 messages?

Comment: @DanialartBiz Right, you'd need to separately query for the count in that case so it's better to reverse the sort instead to specifically get the last docs.